# How to throw custom exception instead of NoSuchElementException in selenium

Tags: java, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I wish to throw a custom error message in selenium when an element's xpath is not found
I have created a class

```
package NewPackage;

public class ExplicitAssertionError extends AssertionError {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ExplicitAssertionError (String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

I have written code like this for testing a page

```
public class ResultPage extends WDBase {
    public void assertTravelNamePresent(final String busName) {
        final String xpath="//div[@class='company'][contains(.,'"+busName+"')]";
        if (!driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed()) {
                throw new ExplicitAssertionError("invalid text found");
        }
    }
}
```

Here when an invalid text is passed that is which is not matching with xpath of page NoSuchElementException is thrown instead of an error message.
Also can anyone provide me a solution to fail a test case using assertTrue/False in cases where element is not found
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `findElements()` method and check the length:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size() == 0) {
    throw new ExplicitAssertionError("element not found");
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how xpath is tested w.r.t size()?

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar it's just that the `size()` would return `0` if there are no elements matching the xpath expression. I think this is exactly what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: This is good for checking isDisplayed() how about isEnabled()

Answer (score -1):

You can also use below approach:

```
try{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed()
 }
catch(Exception ex){
    throw new Exception("element not found");
 }
```

Comment: This approach will, though, print an error message but the test will always be passed even though xpath is not found. I need to fail a test when xpath is not found

Comment: If you use above code test will fail with message what you will pass with Exception

Comment: Instead of try..catch can we write just write "throws" and get this done?

Comment: If you are not using try catch the apply Alecxe approach

Comment: Catching all `Exception`s is never very smart, and throwing new ones really pollutes the API, creating a burden for all callers of the method.